# RealmSwift Cannot cast Results<SomeOjbect> to Results<Object>

Tags: ios, swift, realm

RealmSwift version: latest master branch

So I have a Realm Object like:

```
import RealmSwift
class SomeObject: Object
{
    @objc dynamic var datetime = ""
    @objc dynamic var city = 0

    convenience init(city: Int, datetime: String)
    {
        self.init()
        self.city = city
        self.datetime = datetime
    }
}
```

There is a func call like

```
static func createlineData(from results: Results<Object>?) -> LineChartData
```

Now I fetch some results and pass to `createLineData`:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let results = realm.objects(SomeObject.self).filter("city = \(city.rawValue)")
let lineData = createlineData(from: results as? Results<Object>)
```

compiler warns me that the type cast will always fail:

> Cast from Results<"SomeObject"> to unrelated type Results<"Object"> always fails

I am confused since `SomeObject` is just a subclass. How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

What I want to do is that, the param of

`static func createlineData(from results: Results<Object>?) -> LineChartData`

can never be changed, so I need to make a query to filt based on `city` which is enum, pass them into `createlineData(from results: Results<Object>?)`, and access other properties like `datetime` later in `createlineData`, from `Results<Object>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift, each generic class represents its own type and even if you have a generic class where the generic type parameter is a subclass of your other generic class having the superclass as its generic parameter, the two generic classes won't be related through inheritance.

This is why you cannot cast `Results<SomeObject>` to `Results<Object>` even though `SomeObject` is a subclass of `Object`.

Here's a simple example representing the same issue with a generic class:

```
class A{}
class B:A{}

class GenericClass<T> {
    let val:T

    init(val:T) {
        self.val = val
    }
}

let genericA = GenericClass<A>(val: A())
let genericB = GenericClass<B>(val: B())

let upcasted = genericB as? GenericClass<A> //warning: Cast from 'GenericClass<B>' to unrelated type 'GenericClass<A>' always fails
```

Moreover, the `Results` type in `Realm` is a homogenous collection type, so you cannot store different subclasses of `Object` in the same `Results` object, so casting to `Results<Object>` wouldn't make sense anyways. If you need to store objects from different Realm model classes in the same collection, you will need to sacrifice the self-updating nature of `Results` and stick with storing your objects in an `Array` for instance.

Comment: Thanks. Then in my case, If my results are Object type(not using `SomeObject.self`), can I use KVC like objectForKeyPath to access the property? Like `let r = Results<Object>[0]`, `let city = r["city"]`, something like that? If so, please update your answer and I will accept it. Your answer still need a workaround or solution. I'm ok not to use `SomeObject`, but I want to keep self-updating, that's all the reason I stick to Realm.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? You didn't specify that in your question, hence the lack of workaround in my answer... You cannot have `Results<Object>`, since as I've stated, you cannot query all objects from Realm using a single `.objects` call, since `Results` can only hold instances of a single class, which cannot be `Object`, so no, what you are proposing in your comment cannot work. Without knowing what you need to achieve exactly, the only workaround I can suggest (as already stated in my answer actually) is to use an `Array` instead of `Results`.

Comment: see my updated Q. Basically I need to make a query to filt based on `city`, pass the results as Result<Object>, and access other properties like `datetime` in Result<Object> in that func.

Comment: Well, as I've already stated several times, `Results<Object> is not a valid type, so you cannot do that, you'll have to use an `Array` and give up the self-updating property of `Results`. However, from what I can tell, it seems like you are actually looking for a generic function, `static func createlineData<T>(from results: Results<T>?) -> LineChartData` rather than what you have so far. If you really want to make a chart from several types, then you'll need to think through whether you really need the self-updating property of `Results` or not.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is `createlineData(from results: Results<Object>?) -> LineChartData` comes from a 3rd framework, which exactly takes `Results<Object>`, I need to call this function.

Comment: Which framework is that? Just so that I could take a look at the exact function.

Comment: I will create another question instead of the comments here, seems a different Q then and send you the link, thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48127765/how-to-pass-realm-objectssomeobject-self-filter-to-a-function-that-needs-res here's  the new Q. I don't mind changing the framework itself to make it better. It just smells the framework does not design a correct API to use from what you said.