# How to pass realm.objects(SomeObject.self).filter() to a function that needs Results<Object>

Tags: ios, swift, realm

This question is in conjunction with [RealmSwift Cannot cast Results<SomeOjbect> to Results<Object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48125923/realmswift-cannot-cast-resultssomeojbect-to-resultsobject/48126909?noredirect=1#comment83231956_48126909)

I have a Realm Object like:

```
import RealmSwift
class SomeObject: Object
{
    @objc dynamic var datetime = ""
    @objc dynamic var city = 0

    convenience init(city: Int, datetime: String)
    {
        self.init()
        self.city = city
        self.datetime = datetime
    }
}
```

There is a framework: https://github.com/danielgindi/ChartsRealm, which pull data from Realm and draw charts. The framework is written in Swift, and can be used in Objc as well, so it combines `RLMObject` and `Object` types.

It has a function like:

`public convenience init(results: Results<Object>?, xValueField: String?, yValueField: String, label: String?)`

which takes `Results<Object>?`, however I cannot get my filter results as `Results<Object>` type. e.g.

`realm.objects(SomeObject.self).filter("city=0")`

it's `Results<SomeObject>`, and cannot be converted to `Results<Object>`, described in [RealmSwift Cannot cast Results<SomeOjbect> to Results<Object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48125923/realmswift-cannot-cast-resultssomeojbect-to-resultsobject/48126909?noredirect=1#comment83231956_48126909)

How can I solve it?

Because the demo in ChartsRealm framework, it simply read all objects from Realm in `+ (RLMResults *)allObjectsInRealm:(RLMRealm *)realm;`, but in real world, we usually need to filt the results first.

If there's really nothing I can do, I could accept modifying the framework function parameters, filing pull requests for the framework, just to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Results<Object>` does not make any sense as a type, and the methods in ChartsRealm should be generic methods which take a `Results<T>`.

Because in this specific case all that ChartsRealm does with the `Results<Object>` is use `ObjectiveCSupport.convert()` to get a `RLMResults`, an `unsafeBitCast()` to `Results<Object>` should work fine. You could also just call `ObjectiveCSupport.convert()` yourself and pass ChartsRealm a `RLMResults` rather than a Swift `Results` object.